# Options menu in an Android application

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I want to open up the options menu by clicking on my own created button; is this possible?

Comment: Android phones already have this button, why do you need a new one?

Comment: @NikolaSmiljanić There are Android phones that don't have a physical Menu button. You could solve it with an ActionBar or with the proposed solution.

Comment: @Gonan Your point is valid, two years later, but it just shows that I shouldn't have assumed anything :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use the button of the phone, you have to do the following :

define a listener on your button:

```
openMenuButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButton);
    openMenuButton .setOnClickListener(this);
```

and then in the method onClick(), add :

```
openOptionsMenu()
```

Comment: thanks Sephy ... it works ... 
have you done anything like showing something on top of camera view?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`openOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29) method of your `Activity` to open the Menu programatically.

Still, what Nikola said is right - you'd be better conforming with Android's guidelines.

Comment: thanks fort your help ... it works ... the project i am working on requires to open up options menu by clicking on a customized button.

have you done anything like adding a view on top of camera view? i have been exploring and experimenting for a couple of days but still i cant get it done. i hope you can help me out.